# Determine library version?

Tags: c, static-libraries, polarssl

I compiled a program with a static library `libpolarssl.a`

I would like to create a `README` with the library version.

Is there a **programmatic** way to get the version of this library?

Comment: The `README` can be created by the installation script you send to customers. Alternatively, some version control systems can embed strings in a file that represent checkout info.

Comment: http://polarssl.org/apidoc/version_8h_source.html does this work?

Comment: Just call the methods prototyped in the .h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a
[a script](https://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/684597a/scripts/install-rtmpdump.sh)
to do this

```
vr ()
{
  printf "#include <$2>\n$1" > a.c
  read $1 < <($CC -E a.c | sed '$!d; s/"//g')
}

vr POLARSSL_VERSION_STRING polarssl/version.h
```

Answer (score 1):

Polar SSL has an internal version number and the wrappers to export it to your application, see:

http://polarssl.org/apidoc/version_8h.html

```
// Get the version number
unsigned int version_get_number(void);

// Get the version string ("x.y.z")
void version_get_string(char *string);

// Get the full version string ("PolarSSL x.y.z")
void version_get_string_full(char *string);
```

Easy right?